# Importing typescript defintion into JSDoc

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I'm trying to use ts-xor package that returns a typescript def :

```
export declare type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;
```

Here is how I'm using it:

```
/**
 * @typedef {import('ts-xor')} XOR
 * @typedef {XOR<{
             ^^^
  *   small: true
  * }, {
  *   verySmall: true,
  * }>} ButtonProps
  * @typedef {React.FunctionComponent<ButtonProps>} ButtonComponent 
  */
```

I get :

```
 Type 'XOR' is not generic.ts(2315)
```

[image: Edit TypeScript Playground Export (forked)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the import of `XOR` with [JSDoc @template](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template) like the following:

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @template U
 * @typedef {import('ts-xor').XOR<T,U>} XOR
 */

/**
 * @typedef {XOR<{
     small: true
   }, {
     verySmall: true,
   }>} ButtonProps
 * @typedef {React.FunctionComponent<ButtonProps>} ButtonComponent
 */
```

Comment: I'm surprised I have to redefine the template. That's a annoying, but it works thank you !